# How can I submit Google Form using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm making userscript and want to fill in and submit [this Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1-WzTl4ok_pwIxQo4Sy0cG-DUoj80bTTLy8juZuOEaz0/viewform) using JavaScript.
It doesn't matter if I have to embed it in a webpage.

So variables are defined (getting values from page elements), but I can't fill in the fields (after embeding it on page) using this code (just example):

```
var eRtime = $('span#live_time.time').text();
$('input#entry_1609489384.ss-q-short').val(eRtime);
```

Native page fields can be filled using similar code, but embeded form can't. Like it is protected somehow.

Comment: You cannot manipulate code from another domain.  It's an anti-XSS security feature.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible

Comment: Thank you for fast answers!